# Create variable for each ticker on the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, yfinance

I want to create a dataframe with values for each ticker i'm making a request.

Each data frame needs to have the name of each ticker name so when i call the variable
MMM i will get data from MMM ticker.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

tickets = ['MMM',
 'ABT',
 'ABBV',
 'ABMD',
 'ACN',
 'ATVI']

for i in tickets:

    value = yf.download(str(i), start = "2017-06-14", end = "2021-06-14", interval="1d")
    value = i = value['Adj Close']
```

In the end, I want to have 6 variables with the name of each ticker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your frames in a dictionary with the ticker name as the key. Then you call each frame based on the key:

```
data = {tick: yf.download(tick, start = "2017-06-14", end = "2021-06-14", interval="1d")['Adj Close'] for tick in tickets}
data['MMM'] # call the MMM frame
```

Comment: what if i only want to store the 'Adj Close' ? This will save some computional time right?

Comment: @TiagoEmanuelPratas see the update. Dictionary comprehension should be pretty efficient.